# Efficient way to define an introspective C++ class hierararchy description ?

Tags: c++, introspection

I have a C++ class hierarchy defined by inheritance and I store a description of this hierarchy in it that I can later use for introspection. I would like to know if there is a more efficient or cleaner way to define this than the way I currently do it. 
Here is a stripped down version of my code

```
// in header file (hpp)
struct Type
{
    Type( const string& n, const Type* p = nullptr ) : name(n), parent(p) {}
    const string name;
    const Type* parent;
};

class Base
{
public:
    static const Type m_type;
    virtual const Type& type() const { return m_type; } 
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    static const Type m_type;
    const Type& type() const { return m_type; }
};

// in implementation file (cpp)
const Type Base::m_type( "Base" );
const Type Derived::m_type( "Derived", &Base::m_type );
```

Comment: Do you always have a single base class ?

Comment: Yes, for the classes where I use this. You are right, it should be fixed to cover multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily more efficient but think whether you actually want to require a common base class. An alternative approach uses a global type information registry. Then querying a type’s type information is done via `TypeInfo::get(my_variable)` or `TypeInfo::get(typeid(my_type))`.

This has the advantage that it also works with existing types, which just need to be added to this type info registry.

Internally, the registry would use a map from `std::type_info` to `Type` or similar. The following is a proof of concept. Unfortunately the code doesn’t compile on either clang or GCC. Based on the error messages, I’m suspecting a bug but I could also be wrong …

```
struct Type {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Type*> parents;
    // TODO Extend by fully-qualified name (namespace) etc.

    template <typename... T>
    Type(std::string&& name, T*... parents)
        : name(name), parents{parents...} { }
};

struct TypeInfo {
    template <typename T>
    static Type const& get(T const&) { return get(typeid(T)); }

    template <typename T>
    static Type const& get() { return get(typeid(T)); }

    static Type const& get(std::type_info const& info) {
        auto i = types.find(info);
        if (i == types.end())
            throw unknown_type_error(info.name());

        return i->second;
    }

    template <typename T>
    static void register_type(Type&& type) {
        types.insert(std::make_pair(typeid(T), type));
    }

    typedef std::unordered_map<std::type_info, Type> type_dir_t;
    static type_dir_t types;
};
```

Full code available [as gist on github](https://gist.github.com/2710960).

Having a common base class for logically unrelated classes is generally frowned upon in C++, although it could be argued that this is similar to CRTP / mixins, in which common base classes *are* encouraged. So I’d say that there isn’t necessarily anything wrong with the approach if you don’t care for existing types.

Comment: Agree about the missing support of multiple inheritance. How would you populate the global type information registry with the type name ? Could you give a more detailed code sample ? Your idea looks interesting.

Comment: @chmike See update. – I didn’t even mention multiple inheritance. ;-) But yes, that’s of course missing. As well as namespace information etc. :)

Comment: @chmike Furthermore, you should consider the use-case. At the moment this offers not a lot of value over `std::type_info` but I guess you’re aware of this and intentionally simplified the code example for the question.

Comment: It has value since I want to keep control and ensure portability of the type name. type_info is not portable. The use case is to define some object network in a configuration file and instantiate it at runtime. The configuration file needs to be readable and writable by a human and remain valid when the compiler changes.

Comment: @chmike I agree. I just wanted to make this clear. (FYI, I had the plan of developing something similar for some time. Your question actually gave me the impetus to get my ideas into a more concrete shape … unfortunately, I currently have no time to pursue this further …)